# Accessing nativeElement of a custom angular HTML tag

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine

I am writing an Angular Jasmine Unit Test for a 3rd party slider (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-ui-switch) in my application using the following code:

HTML:

```
<ui-switch id="EditSwitch" name="EditSwitch" (change)="togglePageState()"></ui-switch>
```

Typescript .spec file:

```
  it('clicking slider changes page state', async () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();

    spyOn(component, 'togglePageState');

    let slider = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#EditSwitch')).nativeElement;
    slider.change();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(component.togglePageState).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

  });
```

However whenever I run the unit test I get error:

```
HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Windows 10 0.0.0) Test Configuration Component clicking slider changes page state FAILED
        Failed: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of null
        TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of null
            at Object.<anonymous> src/app/configuration/configuration.component.spec.ts:105:71)
            at step (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.bundle.js:89:23)
            at Object.next (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.bundle.js:70:53)
            at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.bundle.js:64:71
            at new ZoneAwarePromise node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:891:1)
            at webpackJsonp../src/app/configuration/configuration.component.spec.ts.__awaiter (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.bundle.js:60:12)
            at UserContext.<anonymous> src/app/configuration/configuration.component.spec.ts:100:52)
            at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:388:1)
            at ProxyZoneSpec.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:288:1)
            at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:387:1)
.......
```

I believe this is because I am using custom HTML tag 'ui-switch'.

How do I use nativeElement on this custom 'ui-switch' HTML tag? Is there an alternative approach that I need to use instead of nativeElement?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not possible because angular `ui-switch` is not contain in html code in runtime.  There are html template code.

Answer (score 0):

ui-switch during runtime will embed some other tags inside it. You should either check those nativeElement using its unique class or id.

It is not possible to check for ui-switch directly.